# How to customize arrows styling to react-responsive carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm using react responsive carousel but I want to style the slide arrow. I found  google that i can change the style in this file, which is located in the node module folder

> react-responsive-carousel/lib/styles/carousel.min.css

I opened the file and I tried to change the color of the next arrow the  CSS class

> .carousel .control-next.control-arrow:before {
> border-left: 8px solid #fff; }

but it doesn't work?

how can I change the style of the arrow?

Answer (score 3):

So, I haven't worked with the npm package you are mentioning. But in my experience with other NPM packages. If you want to adjust the default styling, you could overwrite the styling by using the same classnames and add the styling into your globals.css file. Or even in a different CSS file, you can import into your component.

Example:

```
// ./styles/globals.css

.carousel .control-next.control-arrow:before { border-left: 8px solid #fff; }
```

I don't think its recommended to make the adjustment directly in the node_modules.